# I want to get all login user list at welcome user page so how would i do that?

Tags: asp.net

I  want to get all login user list at welcome user page .show each user can see the login user list.For that I have created a session ["username"] in login page and after that i want to use that sesion in session start method of asax and i want to retrieve all  the login users and store it into application scope and i also want to remove and insert users on login and logout page.so i am not getting a way how would i do that .because i am new to the concept called global asax file
                                                         thanks

Comment: COMMENT if down-vote!

Comment: @CodeCaster By his rep, he is new so surely explaining would be helpful?

Comment: Fully behind CodeBlend here... Unexplained down votes are of no value whatsoever...

Comment: Added to which we should still engage with people and welcome them to the community... What do you think this user's first impressions of SO will be if everyone's first response to the first question he asks is to batter the guy?

Comment: OP: please rewrite your question to show step by step what you want to, what happens when you do so, what your code looks like and what you have tried to resolve the issue. @MartinMilan how do you think established users look up to new users who don't read the help, ignore all hints you get when writing a question and don't improve their question when asked to? Being new is no excuse for that. :-) Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum or question-answer-game, questions should be complete and answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One relatively simple way of doing this would be to maintain a list of "logged in" users in the Application object, together with the time they were last seen. Everytime you inspect the list, you remove any entries that are, say, twenty minutes old...

That's assuming you are running on a single webserver... If you are running on a web farm, I would have thought you would need to consider recording information as to who is logged in in some central source that is accessible to all instances - a database being the obvious choice...

Comment: dear Martin, it would be better if you can submit one example because as i told you i am new to the concept called global asax file    ,